# C# LINQ query to use previous result if empty

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am having a datatable that is populated from an Access DB. The result looks like

```
Month | Sum
--------------
1 | 1464
2 | 1716
3 | 2125
4 | 2271
5 | 2451
6 | 2583
7 | 2671
9 | 2823
10 | 2975
```

You are right - nothing for august!
What I want is, that for august the same value as for july is used. 
Currently I am using this LINQ query to add the data to a linechart:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= System.DateTime.Now.Month; i++)
            {
                var numbers = (from p in dTable.AsEnumerable()
                              where p.Field<int>("M") >= i
                              select p).First();                   
                series2.Points.Add(new DataPoint { AxisLabel = i.ToString(), YValues = new double[] { Convert.ToDouble(numbers["Sum"]) } });  
            }
```

The chart is shown, but for august the september value is used. I assume it is something very basic that I am doing wrong but I simply can´t figure it out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for this specific problem or you are looking for something like whenever there is a month missing pick the data for the previous month?

Comment: @unlimit I am looking for both :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to invert your logic:

```
var numbers = (from p in dTable.AsEnumerable()
               where p.Field<int>("M") <= i
               select p).Last();
```

It goes without saying that this doesn't work when there is no previous month.

UPDATE:

the above asumes that the table you are reading from is ordered. If that is not the case, you have to order yourself (as mentioned by Cyril Gandon):

```
var numbers = (from p in dTable.AsEnumerable()
               where p.Field<int>("M") <= i
               orderby p.Field<int>("M") descending
               select p).First();
```

Comment: Hi Kris! Thanks for your answer. Any idea why the code with the logic "the right way" returns the value for January all the way?!

Comment: @user1204121 That would depend on the SQL statement you use to populate the dataset. Can you show it to us?

Comment: Hi again! Your suggested answer actually works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You are requesting all the months greater than the current month.

```
where p.Field<int>("M") >= i
```

So for August (8), your are retrieving September and greater (9, 10, 11, 12), not July (7).

You have to invert your constraint, and order by descending month:

```
var numbers = (from p in dTable.AsEnumerable()
                          where p.Field<int>("M") <= i
                          select p)
                         .OrderByDesc(p => p.Month) 
                         .First();
```

Comment: Ah my bad! But strange enough your code returns the value for January all the way (the table is ordered by the select query that I run on my database). Any idea why?